# swagger v3 multipart/form-data in payara 5

Tags: java, swagger, multipartform-data, payara

I have a question regarding multipart/form-data problem in payara 5 server.

I have email api (email.yaml) which generated EmailApi.class by swagger. v3:

```
 paths:
  /site/{site_id}/email:
    post:
      tags:
        - email
      summary: send a email with attachments
      description: |
        send a email with attachment
        Role information:  
        - Endpoint access: Administrator according to test site 
      operationId: sendEmail
      parameters:
        - $ref: "common.yaml#/components/parameters/siteId"
      requestBody:
        description: email
        content:
          multipart/form-data:
            schema:
              $ref: "#/components/schemas/Email"
components:
  securitySchemes:
    bearerAuth:
      $ref: "common.yaml#/components/securitySchemes/bearerAuth"
  schemas:
    Email:
      description: Information about email
      type: object
      properties:
        subject:
          type: string
          description: email subject
        start_time:
          description: starting time of test
          type: string
          format: date-time
        end_time:
          description: ending time of test
          type: string
          format: date-time
        all_participants_included:
          description: including all participants or only test team leaders
          type: boolean
        text:
          type: string
          description: email text
        attachments:
          type: array
          items:
            type: string
            format: binary
```

The content-type is multipart-form.

My Application is running in Payara 5.  I have extend ResourceConfig class

```
register(MultiPartFeature.class);
```

EmailApi generated class is like following:

```
@Consumes({ "multipart/form-data" })
@Produces({ "application/json" })
@ApiOperation(value = "send a email with attachments", tags={ "email" })
@ApiResponses(value = { 
    @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "operation successful"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 400, message = "parameter error", response = InlineResponse400.class),
    @ApiResponse(code = 403, message = "User not allowed to perform this operation"),
    @ApiResponse(code = 404, message = "Object with given id was not found in server") })
public void sendEmail(@PathParam("site_id") SiteId siteId, @Multipart(value = "subject", required = false)  String subject, @Multipart(value = "start_time", required = false)  java.time.ZonedDateTime startTime, @Multipart(value = "end_time", required = false)  java.time.ZonedDateTime endTime, @Multipart(value = "all_participants_included", required = false)  Boolean allParticipantsIncluded, @Multipart(value = "text", required = false)  String text,  @Multipart(value = "attachments" , required = false) Attachment attachmentsDetail);
```

But When I register my impl class EmailApiImpl.class to ResourceConfig.class

```
 register(EmailApiImpl.class)
```

It always throws

```
[2022-04-08 04:27:06,129] Artifact pgms-ams-backend:war: java.io.IOException: com.sun.enterprise.admin.remote.RemoteFailureException: Error occurred during deployment: Exception while loading the app : java.lang.IllegalStateException: ContainerBase.addChild: start: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.ModelValidationException: Validation of the application resource model has failed during application initialization.
[[FATAL] No injection source found for a parameter of type public void com.bmw.pgms.ams.mail.boundary.EmailApiImpl.sendEmail(generated.model.SiteId,java.lang.String,java.time.ZonedDateTime,java.time.ZonedDateTime,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.String,org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment) at index 1.; source='ResourceMethod{httpMethod=POST, consumedTypes=[multipart/form-data], producedTypes=[application/json], suspended=false, suspendTimeout=0, suspendTimeoutUnit=MILLISECONDS, invocable=Invocable{handler=ClassBasedMethodHandler{handlerClass=class com.bmw.pgms.ams.mail.boundary.EmailApiImpl, handlerConstructors=[org.glassfish.jersey.server.model.HandlerConstructor@5990f0f0]}, definitionMethod=public abstract void generated.api.EmailApi.sendEmail(generated.model.SiteId,java.lang.String,java.time.ZonedDateTime,java.time.ZonedDateTime,java.lang.Boolean,java.lang.String,org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment), parameters=[Parameter [type=class generated.model.SiteId, source=site_id, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=subject, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.time.ZonedDateTime, source=start_time, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.time.ZonedDateTime, source=end_time, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.Boolean, source=all_participants_included, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class java.lang.String, source=text, defaultValue=null], Parameter [type=class org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.ext.multipart.Attachment, source=attachments, defaultValue=null]], responseType=void}, nameBindings=[]}']. Please see server.log for more details.
```

I google a lot but still have no answer. Will someone help me?